# Reference request: Ansel Adams and a bellows which is not light-tight

Tags: history, medium-format, books, bellows, ansel-adams

It seems to me I read in the past a recollection by Ansel Adams about the job of finding and fixing holes in the bellows but unfortunately I cannot find the source (was it "The Camera" book? Or maybe "Examples: The Making Of 40 Photographs"?).

From what I understood, a little hole in the bellows acts as an accidental pinhole camera and gives a very weak image which is anyway disturbing the main image.

I guess it was (it is still now?) a very common problem with the folding camera and so maybe it was described by many others photographers apart from Ansel Adams.

Is there anyone who can provide me a source/reference?

Comment: Why not just ask how to repair holes in bellows?

Comment: @MichaelC because I am interested in the original source of the quotation.